# databinding in Intellij Idea Java Android project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, data-binding, android-databinding

*databinding folder and ActivityMainBinding file doesn't created in  project after creating.*

Windows 10, Intellij IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate) built on July 27, 2021

**Way:**

- Android project
- Phone and Tablet
- Bottom Navigation Activity
- Lang: Java, Min API: 16 (Android 4.1), Legacy off

**Installed in my IDE:**

SDK Platforms

- Android API 31
- Android 11.0 (R)

SDK Tools

- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-Tools

**My MainActivity.java file:**

```
package com.example.tarkovassistantandr;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.example.tarkovassistantandr.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
     setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

}
```

[Error (file doesn't created so default error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWN0.png)

[No package and file created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpFwl.png)

Help pls, what I should do? Is there a way to resolve this bug and autocreate that file or if I need to create it manually - how to do it?
(rus|eng)

Comment: Possible problem is using Android SDK API 31. Trying to reinstall API from 31 to 30

Comment: can't change API from 31 to 30 `couse Intellij wanna only 31 but 31 is broken (as Intellij says)

Comment: Check if there are ay errors in [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory) after you create a project/ Do you see any errors in IDE right after the project creation?